Android APK fails because it "requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary"
When I try to install my APK, i get the error:
Failure [-124: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]

My steps to build the APK:

Build the APK using Apktool: apktool build app --use-aapt2 --output app.apk
Zipalign the new APK: zipalign -p -v 4 app.apk apk-aligned.apk
Sign the new APK: apksigner sign --ks-key-alias keys --ks keys --ks-pass xxxxx apk-aligned.apk

Zipalign's output shows that the resources.arsc is not compressed:
Verifying alignment of apk-aligned.apk (4)...
      44 resources.arsc (OK)

In my apktool.yml, resourcesAreCompressed: false.
It seems that what the error message states is not the case. Is there something wrong in my process?

Instead of relying on apktool config better open the final APK in 7-zip UI and see if resources.arsc is compressed or not. On what device (model and Android version) do you try to install the APK?

Can you provide the sample apk so others can test too?

I've just run into the exact same issue - I have an APK that I've zipaligned and signed but add still complains that it isn't aligned.

You can try zipalign with 16instead of 4. Google is preparing to change the page size from 4K to 16K. I wouldn't expect that this new alignment is already enforced but who knows may be the enforcing code was accidentally already included in some releases. See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes
